# Prometheus: how to show history data in grafana as current data

Tags: prometheus, grafana

Requirements:
I want to show offline data as current data in grafana.

Example:
I have data in prometheus which timestamp is 7 days ago(from 14days ago to 7 days ago).
Now I want to show it in grafana as current data. Begin from timestamp of 14 days ago, and ensure grafana show the timestamp as current.
So how can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `offset` in the PromQL query.

```
sum by (foo) (rate(counter_total{bar="zoom"}[5m] offset 7d))
```

https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/basics/#offset-modifier